# Allow appointment only 48 hours in advance in a SP Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar, web-application

I have a SP Calendar where students can book an appointement with a teacher. How can i force the students to take appointment only 48 hours in advance?i mean i want to limits the entry date to 48 hours in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `List Settings >> Validation settings` and enter the following formula together with a message that is shown if validation fails:

```
=[**your date column**] < (NOW() + 2)
```

Comment: >Thankyou for your answer. I forgot to mention that disponibiltés dates in the calendar are predetermined by teachers. They add their availability in the calendar. Students can not take a range of hours outside those predetermined by teachers. When I try your formula, it does not work. It prevents people from taking appointments whatever the range of avaibility they select.

Comment: Maybe you should add a bit more information to your question then. Things like: the current structure of your list, the field types, how the whole process looks like right now and how it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i found a solution for this question. Of course there are other ways of doing this but here's what works for me.

- Create a date field, “MinimumDate”
- In my Start date and time ,i put a Data Validation, and configure it to require the date be filled in and that the date be smaller than    or equal to MinimumDate
- In Infopath click on The Data Option in the load form options i creted a new rule to “set a Field’s value”, with the field as MinimumDate, and then click the function button (fx).
- then i add this formula addDays(today(), 2).